# RibbonGroup causes its children lose their DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am developing a *WPF* project and right now I am working on the *Ribbon area*.

Inside of the *Ribbon* I have some controls such as `RibbonComboBox`, `RibbonTextBox`, etc.

I have several `RibbonTab` in my `Ribbon` so I set one view model for each RibbonTab as following:

```
<rb:Ribbon Name="Ribbon">

        <rb:RibbonTab Header="Tab One" Name="tab1">

            <rb:RibbonTab.DataContext>
                <vm:TabOneViewModel />
            </rb:RibbonTab.DataContext>
```

So, each control within those tabs inherits their respective view model.

When I run the application everything works as expected. The problem starts when I resize the container window to a very small size, after doing this: ***Every control loses their bindings since their DataContext is replaced by an object called `DisconnectedItem`.***

I have done some research and found that this is due to the controls stop being part of the visual tree and for that reason the binding engine sets their DataContext to `DisconnectedItem`.

What can I do to prevent my controls from losing their `DataContext`?

**EDIT:**

I just found that the main problem comes from the `RibbonGroup` control which after collapsing causes its visual children lose their DataContext.

Comment: That's funny! I didn't realize it was you asking it again. I suppose nothing was resolved through my suggested link?

Comment: @C.Lang Yes, I could not resolved it. Actually in the other question, I was thinking that the source of the error was the `RibbonComboBox` but I just realized that the problem is the Ribbon itself, it causes its visual children lose their DataContext when collapses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a workaround for the `RibbonGroup` control issue [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ca215e48-f946-4901-b5ed-07d0661de26c)

The solution I took is creating a new control which inherits from `RibbonGroup` control.

```
    public class MyRibbonGroup : RibbonGroup
    {
    public MyRibbonGroup() 
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        // Force the bindings to be restored after 
        // the ribbon group collapsed or expanded to a menu button.
        if (e.Property == RibbonGroup.IsCollapsedProperty)
        {
            object objDataContext = this.DataContext;
            this.DataContext = null;
            this.DataContext = objDataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was stuck on this issue! Thx, this solution works for me. Created a new UserControl which inherits from RibbonGroup control and added the above code in the code behind. Then I used that control as the RibbonGroup with the Combobox in it.  <UserControls:NewRibbonGroupControl>...</UserControls:NewRibbonGroupControl> Works perfectly. A shame MS didn't fix this a I've read somewere that this issue is still present in the 4.5 framework..

Answer (score 1):

I usually add `DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneTime}"` line for all ribbon controls as a workaround, which fixes the issue completely. You won't be able to change `DataContext` more than once though.